# Unable to check for Dirty if it is Isolated BTF in adf

Tags: oracle-adf

We are using ADF 12C (JDeveloper).
   In our project we have XML menuItems and boundedTaskFlows. OnClick of any menuItem then respective bounded taskFlow will be loaded and be displayed.We have a business case where for every click of menuItem we are checking whether the AppModule is dirty, if it is dirty we are invoking a diaglog saying do u want to rollback.Now I am facing a problem.

Based on my requirements, I am using **Isolated boundedTaskFlow** in one of my page. Because of this, when I check for the Dirty, it is always returning as False. Here is my code which will check for dirty.

```
    // Check if Application Module is dirty
    public Boolean getAmChangesExist() {
        DCBindingContainer bindingContext = (DCBindingContainer) BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
        ApplicationModule am = bindingContext.findDataControl("HISRootAppModuleDataControl").getApplicationModule(); 
        // Here it is always returning as false If, I am using Isolated BTF
        return am.getTransaction().isDirty();
    }

    private boolean checkAMDirty() {
        if (getAmChangesExist()) {
            if (getConfirmationPopupBinding() != null) {
                RichPopup.PopupHints hints = new RichPopup.PopupHints();
                getConfirmationPopupBinding().show(hints);
            }
            return Boolean.TRUE;
        }
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }
```

[image]
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Key difference between ISOLATED and SHARED task flows is that with isolated task flow, you will get a distinct, fresh new instance of your AM definition.
Therefore, this code:

> bindingContext.findDataControl("HISRootAppModuleDataControl").getApplicationModule();

Will retrieve second instance, if you are in second screen, while in previous screen (before opening isolated task flow), it will return first instance.

As you may be aware, there is another alternative for checking for dirty data:
http://adfbugs.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/pending-changes-in-adf-application.html

Comment: Hello Florin, Thanks for the response. The link which you have shared is not talking about the dirty check.

Comment: Hello Florin, I have enclosed a snapshort of a sample page. There If I switch from different menuItems(Depratments, Employees), we have a dirty check for a default ApplicationModule. But, because few of my pages are using Isolated BTF's so, I am unable to check for dirty. As you suggested I have gone through the link. How can I use that concept in my page? I don't want to use the framework defined one to check for dirty
(i.e., <AF:document uncommittedDataWarning="on"> )

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution for the above thing. ADF is giving inbuit dirtyCheck while switching between the modules. References

[Warning on Saved Changes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/unsaveddatawarning-096556.html)